# Laravel testing - problem with faker image

Tags: laravel, testing, laravel-livewire

I trying to build tests on a Livewire project that uses FilamentPHP. I'm getting an expected string but getting an array error in my test and I have no idea why it's getting an array. I'm 100% sure this happens on the "thumbnail" and "featured_image" fields.

This is what my test looks like:

```php
/** @test */
public function an_admin_can_see_saved_fields_for_edit_screen_for_a_post_from_filament(): void
{        
    $post = Post::factory()->create([
        'is_active' => true
    ]);

    Livewire::test(PostResource\Pages\EditPost::class, [
        'record' => $post->getRouteKey(),
    ])
        ->assertFormSet([
            'title' => $post->title,
            'slug' => $post->slug,
            'thumbnail' => $post->thumbnail,
            'featured_image' => $post->featured_image,
            'excerpt' => $post->excerpt,
            'content' => $post->content,
            'is_active' => $post->is_active,
            'category_id' => $post->category_id,
        ]);
}
```

This is what the relevant part of my migration file looks like:

```php
$table->string('thumbnail');
$table->string('featured_image');
```

Here's what my factory looks like:

```
public function definition(): array
{
    $cat = Category::factory()->create();

    return [
        'title' => $this->faker->userName,
        'slug' => $this->faker->slug,
        'thumbnail' => $this->faker->image(storage_path('app/public/blog')),
        'featured_image' => $this->faker->image(storage_path('app/public/blog')),
        'excerpt' => $this->faker->sentence,
        'content' => $this->faker->sentence,
        'category_id' => $cat->id,
    ];
}
```

If I run the factory in tinker the thumbnail and featured_image are both saved as paths in a string.

If I `Log::info(gettype($post->thumbnail));` in the test before the `assertFormTest` it logs "string".

I've also tried setting the $casts property in the Post model to be string for thumbnail and featured_image but it doesn't make a difference.

I'm not sure if it makes a difference but the real databases is MySQL but for my tests I'm using (in phpunit.xml):

```xml
<env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
<env name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>
```

Please can anyone advise why I get this error when I run my test:

> Array () does not match expected type "string".

Comment: You need to share the stack trace and find which line exactly is calling what and then throwing that error. And one more thing, do not define `$cat = Category::factory()->create();` inside the factory, follow the documentation, use `'category_id' => Category::factory(),`